# Trying to get "current user" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the `/views/layouts` directory, how do I get the current user? I am using Devise, but `current_user` does not work here for some reason, it describes it as an unknown method. I want to do something like:

```
<% if User.role? == "gen_admin" %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to('Admin', users ) %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

I do have a `role?` method defined in my User model, but I still get this exception:

`undefined method 'role?' for #<Class:0x3fcc1e0>`

So how can I get the current user, and access its fields at this level of the source tree? Thanks!

Here is the roles? method:

```
# in User
ROLES = %w[gen_admin teacher_admin student]
def role?(base_role)
  ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
end
```

Comment: can you provide the code for method `role?`

Comment: ok I added the user method

Comment: try to put `self` so that it would became like this

`def self.role?(base_role)
  ROLES.index(base_role.to_s) <= ROLES.index(role)
end`

Comment: What is the error you're getting when you try using `current_user`? Once you can get that working, instead of `<% if User.role? == "gen_admin" %>`, you'll want to use `<% current_user.role? "gen_admin" %>`.

Comment: @Newbie that did not seem to change it.

Comment: @Zaid, here is the error when I try using `current_user`:

Comment: `undefined method `role?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Are you getting that error when you're logged in, or not? I believe my answer should cover bother situations any way.

Comment: If the user is not logged in, current_user will return nil. Your code must account for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code must account for when users are logged in, and when they are not logged in.

If no user is logged in, then `current_user` will return nil (as in your case, which you thought was an error on Devise's part).

Your view code must handle this - eg.

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.role?('gen_admin') %>
```

Comment: Ok, so that got me past the nil:object complaint. Thanks for the info too, I didnt know you had to account for no user being logged in explicitly. But now it says:
`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`, referring to the role? method I believe. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: nevermind, I had to take the 'self' out of the role? method for some reason. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your `role?` method as an  instance method. This means that in order to use it you should first create the instance from `User` class e.g.:

```
@user=User.new
```

Now you can call `@user.role?`

If you want `role?` to be available through the model `User` then you should define it as class method an pass in an object for verification

```
def self.role?(user)

...

end
```

Comment: whoever downvoted this for no reason please explain yourself under this comment.

Comment: not sure but i upvoted it again. people are weird on this site sometimes. your answer was not what I needed exactly but it could certainly help someone else.

Comment: thanks for your support Houdini! Maybe I misinterpreted your question. If you resolved your problem, than I'm happy for you, if not, can you expand on it a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the code in your view to use `current_user` rather than `User`, as well as call the `role?` method correctly (no `==`). If this is used in a view that can be accessed by a non-logged in user, you'll want to confirm that the user is logged in first (so you don't try and call `role?` on `nil`, which would raise an exception):

```
<% if current_user && current_user.role?("gen_admin") %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to('Admin', users ) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No, you do not need to call `authenticate_user` to have current_user set.

Comment: Cool, have not used Devise myself, so I wasn't sure. Removed that part of my answer. The rest of the answer stands, although I guess your use of `.present?` is slightly more thorough (is there any chance that `current_user` would return an `empty` object?).

Answer (score -1):

Do you forget to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your controller? This will ensure that current_user is available in your views

Comment: No, it enforces that the user must be logged in to access the current action.

Comment: My answer maybe unclear but I think it is correct in somehow because if you don't use `:authenticate_user!` in your controller, any access to `current_user`  in views from that controller will be wrong, am I right? Can we still be able to use `current_user` without `:authenticate_user!` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `current_user`. Not forcing login doesn't mean that a user can't be logged in.